# VueJS 3 Prevent re-computation if computed value hasn't changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a chain of computed values like this:

```
var lt = reactive({
    scrollTop: shallowRef(0),
    row: computed(() => Math.floor(lt.scrollTop / lt.rowHeight)),
    records: computed(() => props.collection.filter((x, i) => {
       console.log(lt.row);
       return i > row && i < row + 30;
    }))
})
```

`scrollTop` is tied to a scroll listener. This setup works, but I notice that the `records` computed is getting recalculated even though `row` hasn't actually changed. I understand this happens because `scrollTop` changes, and triggers the proxies all the way down the chain.

Is there a way to ensure a computed doesn't change unless there's an actual value change in a direct contributor var? If not, is there a better pattern for the data here that would solve this?

Comment: It's unnecessary to keep `lt` monolithic object. If it serves a purpose, all these reactive values could be different variables. Any way, this doesn't matter here, scrollTop shouldn't affect it. These are props.collection and lt.row that trigger records updates, something you didn't take into account.